# php - new PDO() and new mysqli() hanging, but MySQL shows connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

In the following code, the call to `new PDO()` never returns:

```
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=mycluster;port=3306;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF8';

    // Trying various options to resolve potential communication issues. These had
    // no effect, but are retained so we can eliminate them.
    $options = [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTER_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'",
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'password', $options);

    print "\ncreated new PDO!";    // <-- never reaches here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();        // <-- never reaches here
}

print "\n\nFinished!\n";           // <-- never reaches here
```

Interestingly, if I use the mysql client running in the same environment, I can connect using the same credentials.

Even more interestingly, when I `show processlist` in MySQL, I see the remnants of previous attempts to connect:

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------------------------------+
| Id     | User          | Host              | db       | Command         | Time   | State         | Info                             |
+------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------------------------------+
| 373936 | user          | 240.16.7.14:47544 | mydb     | Sleep           |   1575 |               | NULL                             |
| 377508 | user          | 240.16.7.14:37742 | mydb     | Sleep           |     37 |               | NULL                             |
+------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+--------+---------------+----------------------------------+
```

Which tells me that the a connection is being made, and one side or the other is waiting for something. You can see some of my attempts above to get PDO and mysql to be friends, but those attempts were not successful.

This is part of a move to a new environment and the code has been running without trouble in the previous environment (also containerized), but with older versions of both php and MySQL.

MySQL Innodb Cluster version 8.0.32

PHP version 8.1.17

If I attempt to connect, then kill the process in mysql, `new PDO()` will return with no error. That seems to confirm that `new PDO()` is waiting for a response of some sort from the server.

The mysql log shows nothing until I terminate the php process, at which point it shows `...[Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 392961 to db: 'mydb' user: 'user' host: '240.16.7.14' (Got an error reading communication packets).` - bot to iterate, there is NO message until after I terminate the php process.

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "aborted_%";` yields a probably-not-useful (there are lots of attempts going on, most of them from other code):

```
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| Aborted_clients  | 20    |
| Aborted_connects | 10428 |
+------------------+-------+
```

I have now been able to confirm that the same issue happens when I try to connect using `mysqli` as well as with `PDO`.

After getting a docker image set up, I can successfully connect and execute queries with the x protocol. However it freezes when I try to close the connection:

```
$session = mysql_xdevapi\getSession('mysqlx://user:password@mycluster');
$session->sql('USE mydb')->execute();
$rows = $session->sql('SELECT * FROM `my_table` where `id` < 10')->execute();
var_dump($rows->fetchAll());     // <-- lots of yummy data
$session->close();               // <-- hangs here (does not throw)
print "complete!"                // <-- never reaches here
```

But on the bright side the queries work! There is definitely some weird behavior (also hangs on `die`), but I'm not sure it's worth tracking.

The documentation for this is almost nonexistent, however. Some functions are not implemented yet, and it's generally a mess. NOTHING goes to the logs when executing this.

Comment: What is/are results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "aborted_%";

Comment: SELECT @@log_error;  to determine error log filename and see if any messages are there related to your attempt to connect.  Could be a permissions problem or any other detail.

Comment: Permissions doesn't seem likely since I can connect from the same VM from the command line with the same credentials, and perform tasks on the same database.

Comment: also tried with php 8.2.4

Comment: Have you tried any of the solution here yet? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19139/8542

Comment: Yes, went down that list, boosted `max_allowed_packet` and already had `max_connections` at a very high number. `interactive_timeout` doesn't seem to be relevant because it NEVER times out. At this point I do think it's due to a setting on the MySQL cluster, but haven't tracked down what.

Comment: a more generic `Got an error reading communication packets` message shows in the mysql logs for auth failures, so that error in my environments seems to just mean, "something went wrong"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have AN answer, but I certainly hope it's not THE answer.

Despite using php 8.2, and despite auth demonstrably succeeding above, and despite getting different errors when auth fails, and despite seeing the `auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password` listed in `phpinfo()`,  changing the user account on the server to use `mysql_native_password` fixed the problem.

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: is your pdo libmysql-based on mysqlnd-based?